# find vs. locate

Tags: find, locate

There are the commands `find` and `locate` to search for files on the disk.

I know that `find` recursively processes all needed subdirectories to search files and therefore is slow but up-to-date, whereas `locate` uses a database that gets updated every now and then (when exactly?) to quickly show results which might be outdated though.

Are there any other differences? In which situations would one prefer the one or the other? And when does the `locate` database get updated usually?

Comment: Reference: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60205/locate-vs-find-usage-pros-and-cons-of-each-other

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/updatedb.8.html "
       updatedb  is  usually  run  daily  by  cron(8)  to  update  the default
       database."

Comment: @Rinzwind The linked U&L answer is awesome, it's a shame we can't make cross-site duplicates. But do you know more about the cronjob, when exactly will it run? After startup? At a specific time (I think I've read 1-2AM or something like that) only? What happens if it's shut down at that time? Does it start when the computer is on idle? How can I see the database's age?

Comment: @ByteCommander - That's what `anacron` is for. I don't know if it's installed by default on desktop systems/servers, but it is on notebooks. It runs upon boot and sees if any cron  jobs should have run while the system was off and runs them. It's really helpful, but can cause some issues if you have jobs scheduled far away from midnight. That can cause the job to be run upon boot and then again when the time comes up - possibly a lot less than 24 hours later (for a daily job.)

Comment: @Joe So will it run during boot and slow it down, or will it run some time after boot, or does it usually run with such a low priority that it just runs when the system is almost on idle?

Comment: @ByteCommander - It's a settable parameter. It usually runs around 10 or 15 minutes after boot to avoid such problems. I don't know what, if anything, it does with priorities. I suspect nothing. It has its own table similar to crontab which allows very fine control of how it works, but is usually fine with just the defaults.

Comment: @ByteCommander I added an answer with time it takes for `updatedb` to run which is only 3 to 4 seconds on my machine with 1 SSD (4 partitions), 1 HDD (1 partition)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`locate` is really only good for finding files and displaying them to humans. You can do a few things with it, but I wouldn't trust it enough to parse and —as you say— it's impossible to guarantee the state of the internal database, more so because it's only scheduled to run from `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`, once a day!

`find` is live. It filters, excludes, executes. It's suitable for parsing. It can output relative paths. It can output full paths. It can do things based on attributes, not just names.

`locate` certainly has a place in my toolbox but it's usually right at the bottom as a last-ditch effort to find something. It's easier than `find` too.

Comment: I find `locate` to be much faster if I want to search my entire filesystem. And you can manually update the database using `updatedb` before using it.

Comment: You know how that cronjob is exactly configured? Does it run at a specific time or when the system is on idle or n minutes after startup? Because I think I have read somewhere that it is scheduled at 1-2AM, when my machine is usually turned off. Will it never get updated then, except manually (`sudo updatedb`)? And is there a chance to see how old the database is?

Comment: [`grep run-parts /etc/crontab`](http://serverfault.com/a/135940/2619) You'll see that these are being managed through `anacron` (which you'll see through `man anacron` is more resilient to systems that aren't on all the time). From what I can see it should run it on boot instead if you miss the original cron time.

Comment: I find that locate doesn't index my removable/unmounted partitions, so if I want to find something on them, I have to use find. Of course, locate doesn't have all the amazing options that find does - like `-exec command {} \;` to run a command on every file found. I do like to use `locate -b` which restricts locate to finding files which match on the final component of the name - without the rest of the path. I often try that first because it's so fast. Also, you can run `sudo updatedb` any time you want to to refresh the locate database.

Comment: if you need real time search that is also somewhat easy, you can use something like `ls -R | grep 'file_name.txt'`

Answer (score 11):

As much as I like Oli (which is a lot!) I disagree with him on the `find` command. I don't like it.

### `find` command takes over three minutes

Take for example this simple command:

```
$ time find / -type f -name "mail-transport-agent.target"
find: ‘/lost+found’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/ssmtp’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/ssl/private’: Permission denied
    (... SNIP ...)
find: ‘/run/user/997’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/sudo’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/systemd/inaccessible’: Permission denied

real    3m40.589s
user    0m4.156s
sys     0m8.874s
```

It takes over **three minutes** for `find` to search everything starting from `/`. By default reams of error messages appear and you must search through them to find what you are looking for. Still it is better than `grep` to search the whole drive for a string which takes **53 hours**: [`grep`ing all files for a string takes a long time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005437/greping-all-files-for-a-string-takes-a-long-time)

I know I can fiddle with the find command's parameters to make it work better but the point here is the amount of time it takes to run.

### `locate` command takes less than a second

Now let's use `locate`:

```
$ time locate mail-transport-agent.target
/lib/systemd/system/mail-transport-agent.target

real    0m0.816s
user    0m0.792s
sys     0m0.024s
```

The **locate** command takes less than a second!

### `updatedb` only run once a day by default

It is true the `updatedb` command which updates the **locate database** is only run once a day by default. You can run it manually before searching for files just added by using:

```
$ time sudo updatedb

real    0m3.460s
user    0m0.503s
sys     0m1.167s
```

Although this will take 3 seconds, it's small in comparison to `find` command's 3+ minutes.

I've updated my `sudo crontab -e` to include the line at the bottom:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  0 0  1   *   *     /bin/journalctl --vacuum-size=200M
*/5 *  *   *   *     /usr/bin/updatedb
```

Now every five minutes `updatedb` is run and `locate` commands database is almost always up-to-date.

### But there are no attributes?

You can pipe `locate` output to other commands. If for example you want the file attributes you can use:

```
$ locate mail-transport-agent.target | xargs stat
  File: '/lib/systemd/system/mail-transport-agent.target'
  Size: 473         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10305h/66309d   Inode: 667460      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-03-31 18:11:55.091173104 -0600
Modify: 2017-10-27 04:11:45.000000000 -0600
Change: 2017-10-28 07:18:24.860065653 -0600
 Birth: -
```

### Summary

I posted this answer to show the speed and ease of use of `locate`. I tried to address some of the command short-comings pointed out by others.

The `find` command needs to traverse the entire directory structure to find files. The `locate` command has it's own database which gives it lightning speed in comparison.

Comment: @EliahKagan But the find command was scrolling through and listing all the directories and files on all the drives an partitions. It appeared to be working and I was expecting a printout at the end... Either way it wasn't about "fixing" the find command's search it was about getting the time. Running `locate / display-auto-brightness` takes 17 seconds and also displays every directory and file on all disks.

Comment: @EliahKagan I understand. `--regex` was necessary because there were too many results returned with my search string. I'll find two new examples for find and locate and update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: To clarify Eliah's point, that `find` command means *"print the filenames of all the files in the directories `/` and `display-auto-brightness`."* I think you meant to use `find / -name display-auto-brightness`, but even that prints a lot of junk "Permission denied" errors.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes as I said the point wasn't to find the file, it was to time the find command. I'm rerunning tests now with valid parameters after flushing caches. Then I'll update the answer.

Comment: @EliahKagan I've revised the answer with a file name everyone has on their system so they can test the results for themselves. I've included the correct syntax for `find` to search based on `-name` starting at `/`. I feel the `locate` command can be very valuable to most people and deserved an answer on Byte's Question.

Comment: FWIW, some of us are still using 14.04, which doesn't use systemd.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks for the edit--that clarifies what you're talking about. (It occurs to me that a possible interpretation of [that other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944538/taking-out-access-denied-lines) is as a partial [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378); in some cases, it is reasonable to use `locate` instead of `find`, and then one automatically avoids "Permission denied" messages. I don't know if you want to post an answer there too, and I can't be sure if it would be well received by people other than me... but I'm mentioning it in case you want to.)

Comment: @EliahKagan That question has great answers and it focuses on `find` problems only. Besides `time find /home -iname *.pdf 2>/dev/null` returns two files in `.069` seconds but `time locate /home/*.pdf` returns the same output in `0.463` seconds **7 times slower**! Granted .4 second overhead to search entire database of a million file names for `locate` is minimal I guess.

Comment: @wjandrea **groans** Should I change my search file name a third time?

Comment: @Win No, your example is still valid, and I don't think the processing time is changed much whether the file is found or not.

Comment: @wjandrea The time changes when you use `time locate * | wc` (15 seconds longer) vs. `time find / -name "*" 2>/dev/null | wc.` (can't remember time difference and it was last night)