# Taking Out 'Access denied " Lines

Tags: command-line, bash, find

When I use `find` to see all the pdf files in the `/home` directory, I am seeing `access denied`. To eliminate them I tried:

```
find /home -iname "*.pdf" | grep -v "access denied"
```

However, the result is the same. How can I get rid of these lines?

Comment: Related across SE: [Exclude paths that make find complain about permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87634), [How can I exclude all “permission denied” messages…](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762348), [How do I remove “permission denied” printout statements from the find program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19430), [How to skip “permission denied” errors when running find…](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42841), [How can I filter those “Permission denied” from find output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82515), [avoid permission denied spam…](https://superuser.com/q/179978)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you tried didn't work because the `access denied` output are errors and sent on STDERR instead of STDOUT which is piped to `grep`.

You can avoid seeing those errors by redirecting only STDERR

```
find /home -iname "*.pdf" 2>/dev/null
```

Or as [David Foerster commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944538/taking-out-access-denied-lines/944541#comment1500465_944541) we can more succinctly *close* STDERR

```
find /home -iname "*.pdf" 2>&-
```

However, I suspect you actually only want to search your home rather than other users', so perhaps you really want

```
find ~ -iname "*.pdf"
```

If that throws errors there may be some wrong ownerships in your local config, which you should investigate.

Comment: Grrr, why do people always beat me by 30 seconds? :\

Comment: find: “/home/ihsan/.gvfs”: access denied
find: “/home/ihsan/.dbus”: access denied , for the command ~

Comment: is there something wrong for that? yes i also want to other users home directory which is also created by me to test

Comment: @solfish As far as I know those files should be owned by you. You may want to `sudo chown $USER: ~/.gvfs ~/.dbus`

Comment: @Zanna Ooops, lol. I saw the `~` at the end of his comment, but I just didn't process that he meant he had run your second command :D

Comment: sorry i meant yes second one

Comment: It should be enough to close stderr with `2>&-`. GNU find won't terminate itself if it tries to write error messages to a dysfunctional file descriptor. For the ownership issues `sudo chown -R $USER: ...` would be more effective in case of more files within that aren't owned by `$USER`.

Comment: It's normal for a find run as root to be denied access to individual users' .gvfs directories. It's because of FUSE. Don't chown anything in those directories.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the command was not run as root! ([Why does the find command blow up in /run/?](//askubuntu.com/a/839545))

Comment: OK, find run as any user other than the owner of each mounted .gvfs tree will also get an error. Maybe solfish can clarify the userid used.

Comment: but OP got that error in their own home, running the command without `sudo` as their own user (they used `~`), so that directory should belong to them, and they should `chown -R $USER:` it

Comment: @Zanna: OP used `/home`, not `~`; there's a difference.

Comment: @TRiG my comments stating they used `~` refer to OP's first comment on this answer. My answer itself takes account of the fact that the OP used `/home` in their question.

Answer (score 8):

The access denied is probably being printed on `stderr` rather than `stdout`.

Try this:

```
find /home -iname "*.pdf" 2>&1 | grep -v "access denied"
```

---

The `2>&1` redirects the output from `stderr` to `stdout`, so that `grep -v` can do its job. (By default, `|` only pipes `stdout` and not `stderr`.)

Comment: but for this 2>&1 means  if stderr exists send to stdout?

Comment: @solfish Yup, that's exactly the point :)

Comment: what i dont understand is before "|" as an output ; we got  just stderr right? and after "|" as an input we got this

Comment: @solfish Well, I ran into this problem about a year and a half ago, and I was able to fix it using [a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435652/6122159). But then [a comment below my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333259/filter-command-output-using-grep/36435652#comment60490609_36435652) suggested to simply use `2>&1`... I'm not a bash expert, so if that's incorrect then please do say so :)

Comment: @AndroidDev I suggest adding that different method to this answer as an alternative. [Etan Reisner's criticism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333259/filter-command-output-using-grep/36435652#comment60490609_36435652) was that [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) isn't portable. But `bash` in Ubuntu has it, except [in POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode). I think it's the *best* solution--a file maliciously named `access denied` will still appear.

Answer (score 4):

You probably mean "Permission denied"—which is what [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html) in Ubuntu shows you when you cannot access something because of file permissions—rather than "access denied".

One fully general command that does this correctly (and, as a bonus, is [portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9997/resources-for-portable-shell-programming?rq=1) to other [***nix**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like)es, so long as the error message is the same) is:

```
(find 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | grep -Fv 'Permission denied') 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
```

(Usually you want to pass some arguments to `find`. Those go before the first redirection `3>&1`.)

However, often you will able to use something simpler. For example, you can probably [**use process substitution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936384/1038860). Details follow.

### The Most Common Methods and Their Limitations

The two typical approaches are to throw away [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) (as in [Zanna's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/944541/22949)) or to redirect stderr to [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and filter stdout (as in [Android Dev's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/944542/22949)). Although they have the advantage of being simple to write and are often reasonable choices, these approaches are not ideal.

**Discarding everything sent to stderr**—such as by redirecting it to the [null device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) with `2>/dev/null` or by closing it with `2>&-`—runs the risk of missing errors other than "Permission denied".

"Permission denied" is probably the most common error seen when running `find`, but it is far from the only possible error, and if another does occur, you may want to know about it. In particular, `find` reports "No such file or directory" if a starting point does not exist. With multiple starting points, `find` may still return some useful results and appear to work. For example, if `a` and `c` exist but `b` doesn't, `find a b c -name x` prints results in `a`, then "No such file or directory" for `b`, then results in `c`.

**Combining stdout and stderr together into stdout and piping it** to `grep` or some other command to filter it—as with `2>&1 | grep ...` or `|& grep ...`—runs the risk of unintentionally filtering out a file whose name contains the message being filtered.

For example, if you filter out lines that contain "Permission denied" then you will also drop search results showing filenames like "Permission denied messages.txt". This would probably happen by accident, though it would also be possible for a file to be given a specially crafted name to thwart your searches.

**Filtering the combined streams has another problem, which *cannot* be mitigated by filtering more selectively** (such as with `grep -vx 'find: .*: Permission denied'` on the right side of the pipe). Some `find` actions, including the `-print` action that is implicit when you specify no action, determine how to output filenames based on whether or not [stdout](http://foldoc.org/stdout) is a terminal.

- If it *isn't* a terminal, then the filenames are output as-is even if they contain weird characters like newlines and control characters that could change the behavior of your terminal. If it *is* a terminal, then these characters are suppressed and `?` is printed instead.
- This is usually what you want. If you are going to process filenames further, they must be output literally. However, if you are going to display them, a filename with a newline could otherwise mimic multiple filenames, and a filename with a sequence of backspace characters could appear to be a different name. Other problems are also possible, such as filenames containing escape sequences that change the colors in your terminal.
- But piping the search results through another command (like `grep`) causes `find` no longer to see a terminal. (More precisely, it causes its stdout not to be a terminal.) Then weird characters are output literally. But if all the command on the right side of the pipe does is *(a)* remove lines that look like "Permission denied" messages and *(b)* print what's left, then you're still subject to the sort of shenanigans that `find`'s terminal detection is intended to prevent.
- See the UNUSUAL FILENAMES section of [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html) for more information, including the behavior of each of the actions that print filenames. (*"Many of the actions of find result in the printing of data which is under the control of other users..."*) See also sections [3.3.2.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Unsafe-File-Name-Handling), [3.3.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Safe-File-Name-Handling), and [3.3.2.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Unusual-Characters-in-File-Names) of the [GNU Findutils reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/find.html).

*The above discussion of unusual filenames pertains to [GNU find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/), which is the `find` implementation in GNU/Linux systems including Ubuntu.*

### Leaving Standard Output Alone While Filtering Standard Error

What you *really* want here is to leave [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) intact while piping [*stderr*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) to `grep`. Unfortunately there is no simple syntax for this. `|` pipes stdout, and some shells (including `bash`) support `|&` to pipe both streams—or you can redirect stderr to stdout first with `2>&1 |`, which has the same effect. But the commonly used shells don't provide a syntax to pipe stderr only.

You can still do this. It's just awkward. **One way is to swap stdout with stderr**, so that search results are on stderr and errors are on stdout, then pipe stdout to `grep` for filtering:

```
find args 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | grep -Fv 'Permission denied'
```

Usually you'll pass arguments to `find`, such as starting points (the places to search from, which are usually directories) and predicates (tests and actions). These go in place of *`args`* above.

This works by introducing a new [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) to hold onto one of the two standard streams you want to swap, performing redirections to swap them, and closing the new file descriptor.

- File descriptor 1 is stdout and 2 is stderr (and the unredirected 0 is [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29)). But you can also redirect using other file descriptors. This can be used to open, or keep open, a file or device.
- `3>&1` redirects file descriptor 3 to stdout, so that when stdout (file descriptor 1) is subsequently redirected, the original stdout can still be written to easily.
- `1>&2` redirects stdout to stderr. Since file descriptor 3 is still the original stdout, it can still be accessed.
- `2>&3` redirects stderr to file descriptor 3, which is the original stdout.
- `3>&-` closes file descriptor 3, which is no longer needed.
- For more information, see [How to pipe stderr, and not stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout) and [IO Redirection - Swapping stdout and stderr (Advanced)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299317/io-redirection-swapping-stdout-and-stderr-advanced) and especially [pipe only stderr through a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618078/pipe-only-stderr-through-a-filter).

However, this method has the disadvantage that **search results are sent to stderr and errors are sent to stdout**. If you're running this command directly in an interactive shell and not piping or redirecting the output any further, then that doesn't really matter. Otherwise, it may be a problem. If you put that command in a script, and then someone (perhaps you, later) redirects or pipes its output, it does not [behave as expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

The solution is to **swap the streams back after you're done filtering the output**. Applying the same redirections shown above on the right side of the pipeline won't achieve this, because `|` only pipes stdout, so that side of the pipeline only receives output that was originally sent to stderr (because the streams were swapped) and not the original stdout output. Instead, you can use `(` `)` to run the above command [in a subshell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) ([related](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping)), then apply the swapping redirections to that:

```
(find args 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | grep -Fv 'Permission denied') 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
```

It's the grouping, not specifically the subshell, that makes this work. If you prefer, you can use `{` `;}`:

```
{ find args 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | grep -Fv 'Permission denied'; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
```

### A Less Cumbersome Way: Process Substitution

Some shells, including Bash on systems that can support it (including GNU/Linux systems like Ubuntu), let you perform [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), which allows you to run a command and redirect to/from one of its streams. You can redirect the `find` command's stderr to a `grep` command that filters it, and redirect that `grep` command's stdout to stderr.

```
find args 2> >(grep -Fv 'Permission denied' >&2)
```

**Credit goes to [to Android Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435652/1038860) for this idea.**

- See also [Pinko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936384/1038860) to [How to pipe stderr, and not stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout)
- Both those examples use `1>&2`. I have used `>&2`, [which is equivalent](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_02) ([related](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)). Use whichever you like.

Although `bash` [supports](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell) process substitution, [`sh` in Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) is [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dash.1.html), which doesn't. It will give you "Syntax error: redirection unexpected" if you try to use this method, whereas the method of swapping stdout and stderr will still work. Furthermore, when `bash` runs in [POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode), support for process substitution is turned off.

One situation where `bash` runs in POSIX mode is when it is invoked as `sh`<sup>**1**</sup>. Therefore, on an OS like Fedora where `bash` provides `/bin/sh`, or if you have made the `/bin/sh` symlink point to `bash` yourself on Ubuntu, process substitution still does not work in an `sh` script, without a prior command to turn POSIX mode off. Your best bet, if you want to use this method in a script, is to put `#!/bin/bash` [at the top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) instead of `#!/bin/sh`, if you aren't already.

<sup>**1**: In this situation, `bash` turns on POSIX mode automatically *after* it runs the commands in its startup scripts.</sup>

### An Example

It is useful to be able to test these commands. To do this, I create a `tmp` subdirectory of the current directory and populate it with some files and directories, taking permissions away from one of them to trigger a "Permission denied" error in `find`.

```
mkdir tmp; cd tmp; mkdir a b c; touch w a/x 'a/Permission denied messages.txt' b/y c/z; chmod 0 b
```

One of the directories that *is* accessible includes a file with "Permission denied" in its name. Running `find` with no redirections or pipes shows this file, but also shows the actual "Permission denied" error for another directory that *isn't* accessible:

```
ek@Io:~/tmp$ find
.
./a
./a/Permission denied messages.txt
./a/x
./c
./c/z
./w
./b
find: ‘./b’: Permission denied
```

Piping both stdout and stderr to `grep` and filtering out lines that contain "Permission denied" makes the error message go away but also hides the search result for the file with that phrase in its name:

```
ek@Io:~/tmp$ find |& grep -Fv 'Permission denied'
.
./a
./a/x
./c
./c/z
./w
./b
```

`find 2>&1 | grep -Fv 'Permission denied'` is equivalent and produces the same output.

The methods shown above for filtering out "Permission denied" only from error messages—and not from search results—are successful. For example, here's the method where stdout and stderr are swapped:

```
ek@Io:~/tmp$ (find 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | grep -Fv 'Permission denied') 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
.
./a
./a/Permission denied messages.txt
./a/x
./c
./c/z
./w
./b
```

`find args 2> >(grep -Fv 'Permission denied' >&2)` produces the same output.

You can trigger a different error message to ensure that lines sent to stderr that *don't* contain the text "Permission denied" are still allowed through. For example, here I have run `find` with the current directory (`.`) as one starting point, but the nonexistent directory `foo` as another:

```
ek@Io:~/tmp$ (find . foo 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | grep -Fv 'Permission denied') 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
.
./a
./a/Permission denied messages.txt
./a/x
./c
./c/z
./w
./b
find: ‘foo’: No such file or directory
```

### Checking That `find`'s Standard Output is Still a Terminal

We can also see which commands cause special characters, such as newlines, to be displayed literally. (This can be done separately from the demonstration above, and it doesn't need to be in the `tmp` directory.)

Make a file with a newline in its name:

```
touch $'abc\ndef'
```

Usually we use directories as starting points for `find`, but files work too:

```
$ find abc*
abc?def
```

Piping stdout to another command causes the newline to be outputted literally, creating the false impression of two separate search results `abc` and `def`. We can test that with `cat`:

```
$ find abc* | cat
abc
def
```

Redirecting just stderr does not cause this problem:

```
$ find abc* 2>/dev/null
abc?def
```

Nor does closing it:

```
$ find abc* 2>&-
abc?def
```

Piping to `grep` *does* cause the problem:

```
$ find abc* |& grep -Fv 'Permission denied'
abc
def
```

(Replacing `|&` with `2>&1 |` is equivalent and produces the same output.)

Swapping stdout and stderr and piping stdout does *not* cause the problem—`find`'s stdout becomes stderr, which is *not* piped:

```
$ find abc* 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | grep -Fv 'Permission denied'
abc?def
```

Grouping that command and swapping the streams back does not cause the problem:

```
$ (find abc* 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | grep -Fv 'Permission denied') 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
abc?def
```

(The `{` `;}` version produces the same output.)

Using process substitution to filter stderr does not cause the problem either:

```
$ find abc* 2> >(grep -Fv 'Permission denied' >&2)
abc?def
```