# Improve initial use of `find` performance time

Tags: command-line, performance, ram, find, cache

I'm working on a project to find all the `.tar` installation files on my system using the command:

```bsh
time find / -type f \( -name "*.tar" -o -name "*.tar.*" \) 2>/dev/null | wc
```

The first time it runs I get:

```
real    1m10.767s
```

The second time it runs I get:

```
real    0m9.847s
```

I would like to always get the second time performance of **< 10 seconds** and forgo the initial performance of **1 minute 10 seconds**. What is the best way of avoiding the one minute penalty the first time `find` is used?

---

#### Notes

- Your initial `find` may be faster because I have one Ubuntu 16.04 installation plus two Windows 10 installations for a total of 2 million files.
- OTOH your initial `find` may be slower as I have Ubuntu 16.04 and one of the Windows 10 installations on a **Samsung Pro 960 NVMe SSD** rated at 3,000 MBps whereas hard drives are rated at 140 MBps and good SSDs are rated at 400 MBps.
- If you want to replicate tests but have no `.tar` files on your system, replace `tar` with `bashrc` in the section: `-name "*.tar" -o -name "*.tar.*"`.

---

### TL;DR

#### Drop RAM caches that speed up `find` disk access

You can repeat first/second performance tests by calling this little script before the first `find`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]] ; then echo "Please run as root" ; exit 1 ; fi
sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

#### GIF showing how much RAM disk caching consumes

The `find` command run across `/` will consume about 500 MB of cache buffers as the `.gif` below shows when they are dropped:

[image: drop_caches.gif]

^^^--- Notice the memory line immediately below the terminal window shows a drop from 4.74 GiB to 4.24 GiB. It actually drops to 4.11 GiB after the `peek` screen recorder saves the file and closes. On my system `find` disk caching is using about 5% of RAM.

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent the [`locate`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/locate.findutils.1.html) command?

Comment: @PerlDuck Actually I am because `locate` doesn't allow searching for two patterns at once :)

Comment: @PerlDuck The other problem is locate doesn't index the `/tmp` directory where some users might choose to download there `.tar.XXX` files. The `locate` commands that work best though are: `locate .tar.` (0.5 seconds) followed by `locate -r "\.tar$"` (0.8 seconds). The total of **1.3** seconds is much faster than RAM cached `find` which is **9.8** seconds.

Comment: Sure. Because `locate` operates on a "database" (I don't know the exact format, but let's think of it as a CSV file which is grep'ed). This DB (`/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`) is updated once a day (via `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`).

Comment: My manpage for `locate` says `locate [OPTION]... PATTERN...`. The ellipsis … after PATTERN indicates that you can supply any number of PATTERNs. Also, in `/etc/updatedb.conf` you can configure the search paths and add `/tmp`.

Comment: @PerlDuck I'm a big fan of `locate`. I have my `sudo crontab -e` updating every 15 minutes with the line: `*/15 * *   *   *     /usr/bin/updatedb`.

Comment: @PerlDuck Technically you don't actually add `/tmp` you remove it from the pruned directories list. But it's still not something all users want to do. Also there are many who hate the `locate` command and prefer the `find` command. It is this audience I'm catering too.

Comment: Hmmm... It's 7 minutes 32 seconds verses 9.8 seconds on my computer. I do not think there is a way to jump to the second, shorter time, because the first time is needed such that stuff is left in the memory cache for the second time.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you want to achieve. You like `locate` and even configured it to update every 15 minutes, you know how to configure it to search `/tmp`, and you know that it accepts multiple search patterns. So why don't you stick with it?

Comment: @PerlDuck For the final project I will use `locate` and `find` and leave it up to the user to comment out one line or the other. I'll take your vote to have the `find` command commented out and the `locate` command un-commnented. PS if the script is called with a valid `.tar` file name no search is performed to select from all downloaded `.tar` files.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is (overkill but): 1) do `find / -type f > /tmp/filelist-cached` at boot, 2) put the results in a SQLite DB, 3) setup `inotifywait` to monitor all your filesystem activity and update the SQLite DB accordingly, and 4) have a custom script that `selects` in the DB. This will speed up finding files (how often is that required?) but slow down every. thing. else. Your choice.

Comment: @PerlDuck This was initially a self-answered and much to my horror the answer didn't work. I quickly deleted my answer and then spent a few hours testing different things and revised the deleted answer many times. I've "un-deleted" the answer just now.

Comment: @DougSmythies Your 7 min 32 seconds must be on a spinning-platter? People don't reboot and run `find` command first thing. They sign onto websites, search stuff and maybe see a `find` command to try out after their second cup of coffee. So the seven minute background job would be complete and your `find` will be primed for lightening access. That is my theory anyway :)

Comment: I never saw your answer. This seems to work fine for me, and gets the same answer and takes 1.5 seconds: `time locate --regex "\.tar\." "\.tar$" | wc -l`

Comment: @DougSmythies As commented to PerlDuck 3 comments up I deleted my answer then un-deleted it a few hours later after revisions. Thanks for the correct `locate` command syntax. My results are `1.061` seconds. I already love the `locate` command and have been promoting it over the `find` command: https://askubuntu.com/a/1020944/307523 but there are many who **hate** using `locate` so  I'm trying to love `find` like that group. But I have to get over these speed-bumps that are slowing down my love...

Comment: @DougSmythies @PerlDuck Would you write an answer to solve the problem with `locate`? I think it'd be good to have both approaches represented here – the whole discussion above has a lot to commend it.

Comment: @PerlDuck see comment above

Answer (score 2):

## Challenging project

In the following sections are things that should work but don't work. In the end the only "sure-fire" way of making this work was with this bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# NAME: find-cache
# DESC: cache find command search files to RAM
# NOTE: Written for: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027186/improve-initial-use-of-find-performance-time?noredirect=1#comment1669639_1027186

for i in {1..10}; do
    echo "========================" >> /tmp/find-cache.log
    printf "find-cache.log # $i: "  >> /tmp/find-cache.log
    date                            >> /tmp/find-cache.log
    echo "Free RAM at start:"       >> /tmp/find-cache.log
    free -h | head -n2              >> /tmp/find-cache.log
    printf "Count of all files: "   >> /tmp/find-cache.log
    SECONDS=0                       # Environment variable
    time find /* 2>/dev/null|wc -l  >> /tmp/find-cache.log
    duration=$SECONDS               # Set elapsed seconds
    echo "$(($duration / 60)) minutes and $(($duration % 60)) seconds for find." \
                                    >> /tmp/find-cache.log
    echo "Free RAM after find:"     >> /tmp/find-cache.log
    free -h | head -n2              >> /tmp/find-cache.log
    echo "Sleeping 15 seconds..."   >> /tmp/find-cache.log
    sleep 15
done
```

Copy above text to a script file named: `find-cache`. Put the script name in **Startup Applications**. Use the instructions in the next section but substitute the command name `/usr/bin/find...` with `/<path-to-script>/find-cache`.

Don't forget to mark the script as executable using:

```
chmod a+x /<path-to-script>/find-cache
```

`<path-to-script>` should be in your $PATH environment such as `/usr/local/bin` or preferably `/home/<your-user-name>/bin`. To double check use `echo $PATH` to reveal the environment variable.

Every time I login I usually startup `conky` and `firefox`. You probably do other things. To fine-tune settings for your system check the log file:

```
$ cat /tmp/find-cache.log
========================
find-cache.log # 1: Sun Apr 22 09:48:40 MDT 2018
Free RAM at start:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.4G        431M        5.9G        628M        1.1G        6.1G
Count of all files: 1906881
0 minutes and 59 seconds for find.
Free RAM after find:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.4G        1.1G        3.0G        599M        3.3G        5.3G
Sleeping 15 seconds...
========================
find-cache.log # 2: Sun Apr 22 09:49:54 MDT 2018
Free RAM at start:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.4G        1.2G        2.9G        599M        3.3G        5.3G
Count of all files: 1903097
0 minutes and 9 seconds for find.
Free RAM after find:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.4G        1.1G        3.0G        599M        3.3G        5.3G
Sleeping 15 seconds...

    (... SNIP ...)
```

**Note:** between 1st and 2nd iteration free RAM drops 3 GB but `firefox` is restoring 12 tabs at the same time.

**What's going on?** For whatever reason when `find` is run just once in a startup bash job, or a `cron` reboot bash job, the Linux Kernel thinks: *"They probably don't want to keep the page cache so I'll empty it to save RAM"*. However when the `find` command is run 10 times as in this script the Linux Kernel thinks: *"Whoaa they really like this stuff in the page cache, I better not clear it out"*.

At least that is my best guess. Regardless of the reason, this approach works as tested many times.

---

## What should work but doesn't work

Below are two attempts at making this project work. I've left them here so others don't waste time repeating them. If you think you can fix them by all means refine them, post an answer and I'll gleefully up-vote.

### Use Startup Applications

Tap and release the <kbd>Windows</kbd> / <kbd>Super</kbd> key (it has the icon: [image: Winkey1] or [image: Winkey2] or [image: Winkey3]) to bring up `dash`.

In the search field type `startup` and you'll see the **Startup Applications** icon appear. Click the icon. When the window opens click `Add` on the right. Fill in the new Startup Program fields as follows:

- Fill in the name as `Cache Find to RAM`.
- Fill in the command as `sleep 30 && find /* 2>/dev/null | wc`.
- Add a comment such as "Initial run of Find command to cache disk to ram".
- Click the `Add` button on the bottom.

Now reboot and check performance of `find` command.

**Credits:** Windows Key icons copied from Super User [post](https://superuser.com/posts/813102/edit).

---

### Cron at reboot

You can use `cron` to call the `find` command at boot time to cache the slow disk to fast RAM. Run the command `crontab -e` and add the following line at the bottom:

```
@reboot /usr/sleep 30 && /usr/bin/find /* 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

- `@reboot` tells `cron` to run this command at every boot / reboot.
- `/usr/sleep 30` has the `find` command wait 30 seconds before running so the boot runs as fast as possible. Increase this to 45 or 60 depending on your boot speed, time to login and your startup applications to run.
- `/usr/bin/find /* 2>/dev/null | wc-l` calls the find command searching all files (`/*`). Any error messages are hidden by `2>/dev/null`. The number of files are counted using `| wc -l`. On my system it is about 2 million due to one Ubuntu installation and two Windows 10 installations.
- After adding the line use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file.
- After saving the file use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the `nano` editor used by `cron`. If you chose a different editor than `nano` use the appropriate commands to save and exit.

As always the acronym **YMMV** (Your Mileage May Vary) applies.

After reboot I did these tests to prove it **does not** work:

```
rick@alien:~$ time find / -type f \( -name "*.tar" -o -name "*.tar.*" \) 2>/dev/null | wc
     26      26    1278

real    1m10.022s
user    0m7.246s
sys     0m12.840s
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ time find / -type f \( -name "*.tar" -o -name "*.tar.*" \) 2>/dev/null | wc
     26      26    1278

real    0m8.954s
user    0m2.476s
sys     0m3.709s
```

Comment: @αғsнιη Thanks for pointing out that interesting link. However the Q&A is about caching file contents which would take 180 GB of RAM on my system. I only need to cache 2 million file names which appears to take only 1/2 GB of RAM. The linked answer is about increasing `swappiness` to `90`/`95`. Indeed on my system it is set at `60` but it's a mute point because swap is never used. I don't have 10 million line C projects floating around that use 112 MB of headers from `//usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.30-041430/`. Although this is a good link for C programmers, I just have humble bash scripts.