# Which is the right way to drop caches in Lubuntu?

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, cache

I am currently using Lubuntu 18.04

I thought that theese are the 3 right code lines to drop cache:

```
sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

I've tried three all with and without sudo and the output is permission denied.

```
 sudo sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
```

I have all windows closed, no applications running but still permission denied...

I am clearly doing something wrong,
Could anyone tell me which is the right way to drop caches in Lubuntu?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that `>` does not have sudo privilege, many people use `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to do the same job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found something that works...

```
sync

sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"

sync

sudo sh -c "echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"

sync

sudo sh -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

And if you want to drop thumbnails make this:

```
rm -v -f ~/.cache/thumbnails/*/*.png ~/.thumbnails/*/*.png





 rm -v -f ~/.cache/thumbnails/*/*/*.png ~/.thumbnails/*/*/*.png
```

Of course you should use:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
```

And that would be all...
At least I thought so... but I may be wrong...

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is with a script lifted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027186/improve-initial-use-of-find-performance-time):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]] ; then echo "Please run as root" ; exit 1 ; fi
sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Call the script `drop-caches`.

Mark it as executable using `chmod a+x drop-caches`

Call it using `sudo ./drop-caches`

If you place the script in `/usr/local/bin` you can call it using `sudo drop-caches`

Comment: How do I place the script from terminal?

Comment: `sudo -H leafpad /usr/local/bin/drop-caches` I think. I haven't used Lubuntu in a while. After opening your editor, copy and paste the lines above into it. Save the file and follow the rest of the instructions above.

Comment: Sorry doesn't work at all... Terminal close as enter the call if I enter the above and neither work creating the file with leafpad... sudo ./drop-caches makes an output command not found...

Comment: `sudo ./drop-caches` implies it is in the current directory. In this case you would have to use `cd /directory-name` first. If you put the script in `/usr/local/bin` there is no need to use `./` prefix in front of script. Just use `sudo drop-caches` and because `/usr/local/bin` is already in the system's search path it will find the command automatically. The same thing happens when you type `ls` or `cat` or `grep` which are in the search path `/usr/bin` or something similar.