# "locate" command find file but "cat" says it doesn't exist

Tags: drivers, nvidia, libraries, opengl, locate

I'm using ubuntu 20.04, with a nvidia geforce 610M, the last driver installed is 390 for nvidia.

I'm completely lost, recently had issues with my nvidia driver. Now they seem corrected but after my installation, the librairy libGl.so gives me some trouble.

"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so" is required by a program but it can't find it.

Here is the error message of the programm :

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:27 (message):
  The imported target "Qt5::Gui" references the file

     "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:45 (_qt5_Gui_check_file_exists)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:69 (_qt5gui_find_extra_libs)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:186 (include)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Quick/Qt5QuickConfig.cmake:101 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
```

using the commande locate i can find the file :

```
user@user-K55VD:~$ locate libGL.so
/home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-135.4.4221/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/gstreamer/20/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/snap/gstreamer/20/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/snap/notepadqq/855/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/snap/notepadqq/855/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
/snap/notepadqq/855/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/snap/notepadqq/855/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
```

To see if it's really there I tried "cat" which said the file wasn't there

```
user@user-K55VD:~$ cat  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
cat: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: No such file or directory
```

The more I use ubuntu the more I feel I don't anderstand anything that's happening, please can someone explain to me what's going on ?

Comment: Did you run: `sudo updatedb` before you ran `locate`?

Comment: I'm currently in the process of doing it, is it normal that it takes a long time without showing anything in the terminal ?

Comment: okay, it is actually working, now my issue is that my program can't find the file but it's unrelated to y first question so i'll close it, thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find vs. locate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671741/find-vs-locate)

Answer (score 2):

I just had to update the database with sudo updatedb
Now files that are not present do not display.
I still can't find my file but it's unrelated to my main question.